# Excel Chart.Export Rendering Quality

Tags: excel, charts, rendering

I use VBA with Excel 2007 to generate a report, including charts, which is distributed via HTML email using Outlook 2007. I generate the images like this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("report").ChartObjects("performance").Chart.Export sPath & salt & "_performance.png"
```

where sPath is a string representing the absolute path, and salt is a random string to prevent excel from using cached images when I add them to the email:

```
html = "<p><img src='" & sPath & salt & "_performance.png'></img></p>"
```

(I do not add them to the email in any other way)

The quality of the charts generated this way is abysmal. If I use the Windows Snipping Tool and copy-paste manually into the email, the quality is fine. Is there any way to extract the image in a way that does not use antialiasing or other filtering?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know wheather it will help you in your case, but I end up by manually increasing the size of a chart and size of fonts inside a chart in my source excel file. This gives a better image resolution and presentation in your resulting image file.